# React component with async array not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have a component that gets an array of objects from a database using an async - await function. When the function gets the data and sets the array to a State variable, the component doesn't seem to update and I get errors about being unable to read properties. The data is being retrieved from the database correctly because I can console.log it. What am I doing wrong?

```js
export default function LevelLeaderboard ({ level }) {
  const [leaderboardData, setLeaderboardData] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
    getLeaderBoardData(level)
    .then((data)=>{
      console.log(data)
      setLeaderboardData(data)
    })
  },[level]);

  return (
    <div id="level" className="level-leaderboard">
      <ul>
      <li>{leaderboardData[0]['name']}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>       
  )
}
```

Error:

> LevelLeaderboard.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
> at LevelLeaderboard (LevelLeaderboard.js:19:1)
> at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
> at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
> at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
> at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
> at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)

Here's the async function:

```js
export async function getLeaderBoardData(level, handleData){
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(leaderboard, level));
  let tempArr = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    tempArr.push(doc.data())
  });
  return tempArr;
}
```

Comment: The array will be empty on first render so you need to conditionally handle it `leaderboardData[0]?.name` (better to do it higher up in the html, but that should at least let it render once updated)

Comment: Also you can simplify your `getLeaderBoardData` by leveraging map(): `return querySnapshot.map(doc => doc.data());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a conditional rendering to

```
<li>{leaderboardData[0]['name']}</li>
```

something like:

```
{leaderboardData.length >= 1 && <li>{leaderboardData[0]['name']}</li>}
```

since the array 'leaderboardData' its empty when component first render